# Hibernate entity manager looking for tables in different schemas

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I am implementing jpa persistence using hiberante-entity manager in a java web project. 
I have set following property in in persistence.xml.

`<property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="update"/>`

I have a schema for each user. For e.g i have a schema for user1 and one for user2.
If the table 'ABC' is present in user1 schema but not in user2 schema & I deploy the application and it uses user2 db credentials, i get the message 'user1.ABC' table found so the 'ABC' table is not created in user2 schema.

When i tried with following property in the persistence.xml file the table is created in the user2 schema.

```
 <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="create"/>
```

My question is 
why hibernate is searching in another schema i.e user1 if the application is using user2 db credentials? and
I don't want to create the schema every time the server is started so how can i avoid using 
the value 'create'.

EDIT: Below is my persistence.xml file

```
    <persistence xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence" version="1.0">
    <persistence-unit name="XXXXXX" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
    <provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>

    <class>org.axonframework.saga.repository.jpa.SagaEntry</class>
    <class>org.axonframework.saga.repository.jpa.AssociationValueEntry</class>

    <properties>
        <property name="hibernate.archive.autodetection" value="class"/>
        <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="update"/> 
    </properties>
</persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: can you post your full persistence.xml?

Comment: could you post the `org.axonframework.saga.repository.jpa.SagaEntry` as well. Probably you are defining the Schema there , so it is defaulted no matter which DB credentials are being picked up

Answer (score 3):

I am also facing the same issue, and after digging a lot, get to know that the bug is related to the Mysql Connector.
After changing MySql Connector **6.0.5** to **5.1.28** It works fine for me.
I hope It can help you. Cheers

Answer (score 0):

Has the same problem. 
After set `<property name="hibernate.default_schema" value="MY_SCHEMA"/>` the problem has been solved.

Answer (score 0):

Check if you are calling user1 and user2 in your Hibernate Sessionfactory.

Comment: In my case there is only one user (no multi-tenancy) and behavior is the same as described by the author.

Comment: @Scadge having multiple schemas implicitly means multi-tenancy. Each schema is considered a tenant.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to handle `several schemas` properly then use `multi-tenant per schema` also  if you want to update/create/migrate/handle `columns/tables/schemas/databases` then use `flyway` or `liquibase`

**REFERENCES**

Multitenancy  https://vladmihalcea.com/hibernate-database-schema-multitenancy/

Flyway https://flywaydb.org

Liquibase https://www.liquibase.org

Comment: In my case there's no multi-tenancy - only a single user and connection string to specific database, but instead of creating a table in this database, hbm2ddl updates the one in another schema which appears to have the same name.

Comment: @Scadge and please don't hijack other peoples' questions to ask your own.

Answer (score 0):

The Hibernate documentation is clear about this, you need to enable multi-tenant operations [as described in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39393773/how-to-configure-multiple-schemas-with-hibernate) and [this example](https://mariemjabloun.blogspot.com/2014/02/hibernate-jpa-21-use-multiple-database.html).

Basically you have to declare multiple persistence units and have each point to a different schema. Each can then use different login credentials as well.

[Hibernate documentation link](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.2/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#multitenacy-separate-schema)

To summarise:

1. Define your persistence unit
2. Define your mapping files per persistence unit

When using JPA add the following:
 3. Specifying tenant identifier from SessionFactory
 4. Implement a MultiTenantConnectionProvider